# Tomcat Garbage Collection

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection

Recently our Tomcat instances stopped without any logs shown in catalina.out even though the CPU usage is quite low at 5% or so. And htop showed that the memory used was only 377MB/1000MB.

So I enabled the verbose logging. And I found that every time the issue happened. I would see something like this:

855.476: [GC855.476: [DefNew: 4342K->59K(4800K), 0.0018170 secs] 88755K->84472K(103080K), 0.0019020 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

860.850: [GC860.850: [DefNew: 4347K->71K(4800K), 0.0017130 secs] 88760K->84483K(103080K), 0.0017890 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

And I would like to check how to read the above 2 lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) has good information on garbage collection.

> [GC [DefNew: 64575K->959K(64576K), 0.0457646 secs]
>   196016K->133633K(261184K), 0.0459067 secs]
>
> indicates that the minor collection recovered about 98% of the young
>   generation, DefNew: 64575K->959K(64576K) and took 0.0457646 secs
>   (about 45 milliseconds).
>
> The usage of the entire heap was reduced to about 51%
>   196016K->133633K(261184K) and that there was some slight additional
>   overhead for the collection (over and above the collection of the
>   young generation) as indicated by the final time of 0.0459067 secs.